# "Faking" a JavaScript Constructor

Tags: javascript, function-prototypes

**Context**

I am working on improving my JavaScript skills and I'm learning more about prototyping. I want to better understand the code in this question and any limitations or problems with it.

One thing that hasn't been obvious is defining more complex constructors that do more than simple initialization. What I want to do is have a Class that calls a web service when it's created without needing to call a method right after initialization.

What I did was create a property and assign a self calling anonymous method to it. It seems to work like I want it to, but I don't know if there is a better approach.

**The Code**

```
function AsyncOrderLine(productID) {

    var context = this;

    this.autoValue;
    this._productID = productID;
    this._asyncRequestComplete = false;


    this.hello = function () {
        alert("hello world");
    }

    this.constructor = (function () {
        context.hello();
        context.autoValue = "testing: " + productID + "(" +        context._asyncRequestComplete + ")";
    })()
```

}

**The Result**

```
 var _asyncOrderLine = new AsyncOrderLine(1001);
```

Alert Shown: "Hello World"

```
 _asyncOrderLine.autoValue = testing: 1001(false)
 _asyncOrderLine.constructor = 'undefined'
```

In this case I want the constructor to remain undefined once the object is created.

**Question**

Is there a better way of doing this? Could there be any unforeseen side affects using this approach?

Comment: Generally speaking, what you have done is fine. You don't need to expose a property called constructor at all.. you could just have the function run inside AsyncOrderLine. Then you could avoid the assignment of undefined to your _instance.constructor. However, the question is extremely broad and difficult to answer formally. There are endless ways to accomplish what you've done.

Comment: "*What I did was create a property and assign a self calling anonymous method to it.*" - Why did you do that?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I was going to call it something other than constructor and assign a value to it. I renamed it for the question. The issue was I wanted a function to run when I created the Object.

Comment: @dmck But why put the code inside a nested function, and why assign the return value of that function to a property of the instance?

Comment: The *context* varable is poorly named, it is a reference to the instance (i.e. the plain object created by the constructor). Why not call it *asyncOrderLine*, since that's what it is (if the constructor name is descriptive).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to complicate things like that. You can run whatever code you want inside your constructor:

```
function AsyncOrderLine(productID) {

    this.autoValue;
    this._productID = productID;
    this._asyncRequestComplete = false;

    this.hello = function () {
        alert("hello world");
    }

    // Run whatever arbitrary code you want...    
    this.hello();
    this.autoValue = "testing: " + productID + "(" + context._asyncRequestComplete + ")";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, there's no reason for the constructor property.  You can just run whatever code you want in the function body and it will run at the time the object is initialized.  If you want to run asynchronous code (like ajax calls), then you will probably want to pass a completion function into the constructor so the creator of the object can know when the asynchronous part of the object initialization is actually complete because it won't be complete when the object returns from it's initialization.  That would look something like this:

```
function function AsyncOrderLine(productID, fn) {
    // initialization code for the object here
    this._asyncRequestComplete = false;
    ...

    // kick of asychronous networking call here
    var context = this;
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        // process the data response into our object here
        context.whatever = data;

        context._asyncRequestComplete = true;
        // call the completion function with `this` set to point to our object here 
        // so the creator of this object can know when the async part of
        // initialization is actually done
        fn.call(context);
    });
}
```

And, then a caller would do something like this:

```
var x = new AsyncOrderLine(id, function() {
    // can reference new object and it's methods and properties via "this"
    alert("orderLine object is now completely initialized");
});
```